# Nginx responds 404 for Django app but static files work

Tags: python, django, nginx, http-status-code-404, uwsgi

I followed [this tutorial](http://musings.tinbrain.net/django-deploy/) in order to get my Django app deployed on a DigitalOcean VPS with uWSGI and Nginx.  The static files work well but the Django app itself does not. (404 Not Found - nginx/1.9.6)

```
# Where to look for content (static and media)
root    /srv/www/$host/;

# Allow gzip compression
gzip_types text/css application/json application/x-javascript;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_proxied any;
# Look for files with .gz to serve pre-compressed data
gzip_static on;

server {        
    listen 80;
    # nginx docs recommend try_files over "if"
    location    /   {
        # Try to serve existing files first
        try_files $uri @proxy =404;
    }
    location @proxy {
        # Pass other requests to uWSGI
        uwsgi_pass unix://srv/apps/_/server.sock;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure that socket `/srv/apps/_/server.sock` exists. If not, check your uWSGI configuration.

Comment: The syntax of your `try_files` is wrong. Either `@proxy` or `=404` should be the last element - you can't have both. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Comment: `/srv/apps/_/server.sock` exists.

Comment: How can I use `try_files`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `try_files` is to test for the existence of a local file, and if none found perform a default action. In your case, that default action is to invoke the named location called `@proxy`. This is what you need:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    uwsgi_pass unix://srv/apps/_/server.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.